# "object does not contain a definition for <field>" using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, .net-assembly

I have a library and console program which dynamically loads a `.dll` file. In the library I have a `List<User>`. Class `User` exists in the library. I want in my `foreach` each user on List, but I don't know how to do that.

```
public class Class1
{
    public List<User> user;
    public Class1()
    {
        user = new List<User>() { 
             new User() { name = "Smith", age = 19 }, 
             new User() { name = "Mitchell", age = 41 } 
        };
    }
}

public class User
{
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Part code of console program:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
Type Class1 = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1") as Type;
Type User = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.User") as Type;
var testClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Class1);
MemberInfo[] List = Class1.GetMember("user");

FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)List[0];
MemberInfo[] List = Class1.GetMember("user", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)List[0];                
var users = field.GetValue(testClass); 

for (int i = 0; i < ((IList)users).Count; i++)
{
    var us = ((IList)users)[i];
    // How to show name and age?
    // Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, Age: {1}", us.name, us.age); 
}
```

P.S. I edited the code.

Comment: What type of error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) instead of reflection/binding.

Comment: @Sinatr: why? What does this add?

Comment: @Sinatr dynamic won't work for private members unless you tweak it

Comment: Try it with `var users = (List<User>) field.GetValue(testClass);` and remove the casts from your loop.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, [true](http://dotnetfiddle.net/FQrsXf), would be interesting to know about *tweaking* (Google "c# dynamic private" returns some crap).

Comment: @Sinatr One of the crap returned me a [good result](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/05/accessprivatewrapper-c-40-dynamic.html) Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make `user` public, then:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
var type = assembly.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1");
dynamic test = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
foreach(dynamic user in test.user)
    Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, Age: {1}", user.name, user.age);
```

Comment: @Sinatr making user public is not technically necessary.

Comment: @user3231442 I created a couple of projects and used your code.  And after commenting out the first declarations of List and field, your code executes fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are re-using variables so your code as-is won't even compile.
2. Your field is private by default, so trying to access it without specifying `BindingFlags.NonPublic` will fail. (You add the flags the second time but not the first time)  Make it `public`:

   ```
   public List<User> user;
   ```

   (you could also make it a property by adding `{get; set;}` but since this whole thing seems to me an exercise in reflection it doesn't make much difference.
3. You are casting the value to an `IList`, so when iterating through it you just see `object`s instead of `User`s.  So trying to access `us.name` will fail.  You *could* do:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < ((IList)users).Count; i++)
   {
       var us = ((IList<User>)users)[i];
       // How to show name and age?
       Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, Age: {1}", us.name, us.age); 
   }
   ```

   or simply

   ```
   foreach(User us in (IList<User>)users)
   {
       // How to show name and age?
       Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, Age: {1}", us.name, us.age); 
   }
   ```

Comment: #1 isn't applicable (he is using the flag), but #2 is indeed causing the problem.

Comment: 1.Your point 1 is already taken care by OP, 2.OP's code is buggy won't even compile. Can you see that?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the OP tries twice - the first time without the necessary flags.  The OP re-uses the variables so it won'e even compile as-is.

Comment: Oh, now you mention it. I assume that was some testing code he forgot to remove. The error message is consistent with #2 though, if he had a problem with the access it would've told him something different.

Comment: I have error? if I write your code: The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your goal is, but you need to either cast to a `User` to access the fields or use `dynamic`.